# How to monitor changes with Condvar and Mutex

Tags: concurrency, locking, rust, race-condition, wakeup

I have a shared `Vec<CacheChange>`. Whenever a new `CacheChange` is written I want to wake up readers. I recall that a `Condvar` is good for signaling when a predicate/situation is ready, namely, when the `Vec` is modified.

So I spent some time creating a `Monitor` abstraction to own the `Vec` and provide `wait` and `lock` semantics.

The problem now is I don't know when to reset the `Condvar`. What is a good way to give a reasonable amount of time to readers to hit the predicate and work their way to holding the lock? before closing the condvar? Am I approach `Condvar`s the wrong way?

This is Rust code but this more a question of fundamentals for exact concurrent access/notification between multiple readers.

```
pub struct Monitor<T>(
    sync::Arc<MonitorInner<T>>
);

struct MonitorInner<T> {
    data: sync::Mutex<T>,
    predicate: (sync::Mutex<bool>, sync::Condvar)
}

impl<T> Monitor<T> {   
    pub fn wait(&self) -> Result<(),sync::PoisonError<sync::MutexGuard<bool>>> {
        let mut open = try!(self.0.predicate.0.lock());
        while !*open {
            open = try!(self.0.predicate.1.wait(open));
        }
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn lock(&self) -> Result<sync::MutexGuard<T>, sync::PoisonError<sync::MutexGuard<T>>> {
        self.0.data.lock()
    }

    pub fn reset(&mut self) -> Result<(),sync::PoisonError<sync::MutexGuard<bool>>> {
        let mut open = try!(self.0.predicate.0.lock());
        *open = false;
        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn wakeup_all(&mut self) -> Result<(),sync::PoisonError<sync::MutexGuard<bool>>>  {
        let mut open = try!(self.0.predicate.0.lock());
        *open = true;
        self.0.predicate.1.notify_all();
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

After the first wakeup call, my readers are able to miss reads. Probably because they are still holding the data lock while the predicate has been toggled again.I've seen this in my test code with just one reader and one writer.

Then there's the complication of when to reset the `Monitor`, ideally it would be locked after all readers had their chance to look at the data. This could cause deadlock issues if the reader ignore their monitors (no guarantee they should service every wakeup call).

Do I need to use some kind of reader tracking system with timeouts and track when new data arrives while monitor reads are still being serviced? Is there an existing paradigm I should be aware of?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is to use a counter instead of a boolean.

```
struct MonitorInner<T> {
    data: sync::Mutex<T>,
    signal: sync::Condvar,
    counter: sync::AtomicUsize,
}
```

Then, every time an update is done, the counter is incremented. It is never reset, so there is no question about when to reset.

Of course, it means that readers should remember the value of the counter the last time they were woken up.

Comment: *It is never reset*, well every 2^32 or 2^64 increments it is. AKA the `time_t` 2038 issue ^_^

Comment: @Shepmaster: Yes, I wish that `AtomicU64` was stable, as a 64-bits counter cannot physically overflow from 1-increments (for the math-inclined, it takes ~600 years to overflow it with 1 inc/ns, or ~120 years at 5 GHz).

Comment: I could put the atomic load in the `wait()` and the thread would wake up when the reloaded count was higher.